# Request for Tag: Personal-Identification

Tags: feature-request, tags

I Request for the tag "Personal-Identification"

It would include topics related to [ID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_document), like Passport, Residency permit, drivers' License, National Identity card/number, etc.

Comment: Can you give us some examples of questions which could be tagged with this?

Comment: https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/13575/why-countries-selling-passports-is-bad 
https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/10801/why-are-only-certain-professions-able-to-countersign-passport-photos-in-the-uk 
https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/14985/trumps-temporary-ban-and-green-card-holders 
https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/179/how-does-the-social-security-work-in-united-states 
https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/26333/why-does-modi-administration-want-sim-cards-to-be-linked-to-aadhaar-card

Comment: There is no personal identification component to the [green card question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/14985/4666).  That's purely an immigration question.  I.e. it's asking about green card holders as a class rather than about the card or using it as an ID.  I don't really see the other questions as missing an ID tag.

Comment: Green Card is an **Identification card** allowing you to rent housing and get employment in USA. Without a Green card **identifying** you as a "resident of USA", you can't work there legally.